# Cannot shutdown high load docker mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, docker, shutdown

I have a script that launch a docker every 3 secondes until there is 20 docker up. After that, when one is finished, a other docker will be launch.

In the docker, I launch a bash script that will start apache2, mysql and a node script. After a while, the node script end, and the docker shutdown.

But sometime (totally randomly), the docker will hangs there forever and not shutdown. I can't even shut it down from the host with docker stop or docker kill. And if I try to reboot the host, the host will not completly shutdown. I check the stats of the docker and the docker just stay there with almost 0% cpu usage.

Trying to shutdown every process manually in the bash script, I saw that it was mysql that would not shutdown. I try sudo service mysql stop and sudo mysqladmin shutdown but both failed.

Doing a docker top, I can see that the only process remaining is mysql that is currently

If this can help, I launch docker with this commands docker run --rm test01 /bin/bash /home/gps/entry_point.sh 5811fafb27517f523d1b96e5 http://10.1.5.41:8889 master

Both my host and dockers are debian jessie, and most of the time it work fine.

I don't know if this is related to the problem, but when I do a dmesg on the host, I have a tons of thoses messages:

```
[ 4197.073458] docker0: port 7(veth27ee643) entered disabled state
[ 4197.764473] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[533]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4197.809072] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[533]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4197.855061] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[533]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4197.856599] device veth0ef0a9b entered promiscuous mode
[ 4197.857560] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth0ef0a9b: link is not ready
[ 4197.858392] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered forwarding state
[ 4197.859215] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered forwarding state
[ 4198.019272] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered disabled state
[ 4198.119297] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth0ef0a9b: link becomes ready
[ 4198.120103] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered forwarding state
[ 4198.120873] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered forwarding state
[ 4213.166227] docker0: port 7(veth0ef0a9b) entered forwarding state
[ 4523.921860] docker0: port 3(veth65e0351) entered disabled state
[ 4523.973714] docker0: port 3(veth65e0351) entered disabled state
[ 4523.974654] device veth65e0351 left promiscuous mode
[ 4523.975105] docker0: port 3(veth65e0351) entered disabled state
[ 4525.079938] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[533]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4525.136297] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[533]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4525.196855] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[801]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
[ 4525.219241] device veth1658809 entered promiscuous mode
[ 4525.219777] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth1658809: link is not ready
[ 4525.220241] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered forwarding state
[ 4525.220720] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered forwarding state
[ 4525.221500] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered disabled state
[ 4525.494605] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth1658809: link becomes ready
[ 4525.495218] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered forwarding state
[ 4525.495727] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered forwarding state
[ 4540.549216] docker0: port 3(veth1658809) entered forwarding state
```

Any idea on what could cause this problem?

Edit: Not sure if this can help, but doing sudo journalctl -fu docker.service I get thoses logs

```
Oct 27 09:03:32 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:03:32.882004522-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:03:39 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:03:39.56717629-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:03:45 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:03:45.348335753-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:03:52 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:03:52.016592953-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:05:12 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:05:12.142848267-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:15:35 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:15:35.175607108-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:23:50 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:23:50.428877153-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:26:29 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:26:29.223240463-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 09:31:56 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T09:31:56.446979648-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
Oct 27 10:37:18 Server1 dockerd[475]: time="2016-10-27T10:37:18.81258037-04:00" level=error msg="containerd: notify OOM events" error="cgroup path for memory not found"
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you starting up and shutting down all these containers?

Comment: @R0MANARMY We have a bunch of functionnal test scripts, and doing so with docker help us be completly isolated from test to test, and we can run +20 tests by machine (currently 8machines) in parallel. The script that launch the tests will catch every messages and display it on a main console.

Comment: That's kind of awesome, what base image are you using for your containers?

Comment: Please post docker logs output of the hanging container?

Comment: @Farhad Docker logs return only logs of my software (36888lines of logs), there is no error messages about the docker, do you means an other kind of logs?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Simply debian, and then add mysql, apache, my software, everything is automatically updated via git...

Comment: No I mean software logs, You should investigate if some part of your test script is stucking in the problematic container.

Comment: @Farhad when everything hangs, all my software are already close, I put echo everywhere, but it really hangs on sudo service mysql stop, or any kind of commands to stop mysql

Comment: So what happens if you kill mysql process at the end with `pkill` or `killall`? still hangs?

Comment: @Farhad Yes, even tried sudo pkill -9, still hangs. The next echo is never displayed

Comment: Please try my answer and give feedback

Comment: Are you calling `kill -9` from inside the container or outside?

Comment: @R0MANARMY inside the container

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
sudo chgrp mysql /etc/mysql/debian.cnf; sudo chmod 640 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
nano /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
[service]
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf shutdown
sudo chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: I tested it during the night, and sadly it didn't worked. Sometimes my docker logs will finish with Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!, and sometime the failed does not even show